# Dynamic Nested Loop

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic, loops, nested

I am relatively new to programming. As the title suggests I require an algorithm that lets me get the same function of a variable nested loop. i.e.

```
for(..)
{ for(..){
for(..){....}
.
.
}}
```

The Number of nested loop will vary depending upon user input. What I am trying to achieve is finding all combinations of the numbers (10,9,8,7,6,5,4) Now I have read many. Either I dont understand them fully (I am new to programming world) or It doesnt serve my purpose. I need these combinations later in certain calculations and not just print all the combinations. One way, as I have learnt is to use recursion. I dont understand it fully. I tried to make a recursive function but failed miserably. This is what I want

```
10 10 10 
10 10 9
10 10 8
.
.
.
4  4  4
```

The number can change (like 10 10 10 10 , 10 10 10 9 .. ) These combinations are to be stored in an array as I need them to manipulate later. Please keep it simple and comment.

Preferred language will be java. Any Language will do. A general algorithm is highly recommended. P.S. This is not a homework.

Thanks to amit. Here is the working code

```
def findcombinations(array,n,sol,tt=[]):
    if (n== 0):
        tt.append(sol[:])
        return
    for x in array:
        sol.append(x)
        findcombinations(array,n-1,sol,tt)        
        del sol[-1]
    return tt
```

To call the function use
    `print(findcombinations([1,2],3,[]))`

Comment: Pedantically speaking, "10" isn't a digit.  You may wish to reword that.

Comment: Sorry.. I will change that to numbers.. Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you need "dynamic loops" - it is a strong indication you actually need [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science).

For example, finding all possible combinations of size `n` of digits in array [pseudo code]:

```
findCombinations(array,n,sol):
   if (sol.size == n): //stop condition for the recursion
      print sol
      return
   for each x in array:
      sol.append(x)
      findCombinations(array,n-1,sol) //recursive call
      sol.removeLast() //cleaning up environment
```

The above pseudo-code will find and print all sequences of length `n` made from elements from `array` [each element can appear more then once]

Comment: I don't totally follow the dimensions of sol. Like I said I just dont want them to print but use all of them. (Sorry if I am missing something mainly due to the fact I am new to this). Also in java, can u increase the size of array dynamically ? (i.e. sol.append(x)) Also how to calculate n ? Should I calculate the no.of permutations beforehand ? Thank You.

Comment: Actually what is sol in this? :( Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: I am sure am missing a lot. Please explain. I was wrong. Can you be language specific? I thought I could understand from a general representation. But i was mistaken. Thank You.

Comment: @Oasa: No apologies needed. `sol` holds the current permtuation [that you are currently working on]. It is initialized to an empty list when the algorithm starts, and it appends elements on the fly. There are many ways to implement this `sol`, but the simplest one is probably using an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Note that [ArrayList.add(element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29) appends the element to the end of the list

Comment: I understood the concept of ArrayList. Thanks a lot for that. Now sol is an array list I suppose. And initially it is zero.Is "array" is the entire permutation, I suppose. I still did not understand.

Comment: `array` is your input, in your example [in the question], `array = { 10,9,8,7,6,5,4 }`;

Comment: I still dont get it. N is the length right? that is, if i want
   10 10 10 10
   10 10 10 9

and so on, my n =4 right?

If i pass the above array and n as 4. When the function is called, at first the if statement is bypassed as sol is initially null. But then the for statements appends all the 6 values making the size of sol as 6. Then function is called again with n-1 (3) Again the if is bypassed. (Will it ever be equal. Wont size go as infinity and n goes negative? ) and again the for puts the same 6 additional values. I am clearly missing the 'combination part'. Please help me. Thank You

Comment: The example i meant to say is like this  
    `10 10 10 10 \n
    10 10 10 9`

Comment: @Oasa: `sol` is not initialized as null - but as empty list. If you pass `n=4`: with `array={1,2}` it gives you first: `1 1 1 1`, then it comes back from recursive call, and delete the last `1` and print `1 1 1 2`. Then it come back and delete the `2`, and come back one more step and delete the last `1` resulting in `1 1` [not printed yet], and append `2`, resulting in `1 1 2` [not printed], and append 1 to get `1 1 2 1` [it is printed], and `1 1 2 2`, ....

Comment: Let me see.. ({1,2},4)
so.size = 0
So it goes to for statement. It puts the value 1 to sol. ( Due to lack of brackets I did not think the `findCombinations(array,n-1,sol)` as inside the loop itself the previous time.) So it calls now with {1,2},3,{1} Now this goes on till sol becomes {1,1,1,1} The moment size and n becomes equal. If statement gets executed. Wherein it prints 1 1 1 1. Which in my case would be to store in an array for future references. Now it returns to the previous call. It removes last making it `1 1 1' Goes to the next iteration. Making sol 1 1 1 2. calls function again.

Comment: it prints 1 1 1 2. I followed you till this. But I dont understand how it deletes the last two digits. Thanks again a loot. I am beginning to understand.

Comment: Finally I figured it out. Thank YOU. Thanks a looooot. I changed a little in the printing condition to get it working. May be its because of what i understood is wrong. Anyways thanks for bearing me.

Comment: How about the actual code that does it? The pseudo code seems to work it. But what if we just have plain arrays and not other data structures with methods like append() and removeLast()? Please post an actual working code. It would really help!

Comment: @armanali I know its too late. I will post the working code as edit

Answer (score 3):

So you have one or more (well, maybe three or more) numbers, that should be able to range between 4 and 10? One way of doing that would be to have a simple counter and a function turning your counter into an array of numbers.

In pseudo-code:

```
counter_to_array(counter, positions):
  var array = new array(positions)

  for 0 <= i < positions:
    n = counter % 7
    counter = counter // 7  # INTEGER DIVISION
    array[i] = 4 + n

  return array
```

That is, your array is implicit in a counter and you can recreate it as needed. That may not be what you actually need and as written the arrays would go "4 4 4" "5 4 4" "6 4 4"..."10 10 9" "10 10 10", but changing that order is as simple as changing the order the array positions are filled.

Worked example:
We want to generate a 4-element counter, the 11th.

1. We create a 4-element array, called array.
2. We loop through the array positions:
3. We set array[0] to 8 (4 + (11 mod 7)))
4. We set counter to 1 (11 div 7)
5. We set array[1] to 5 (4 + (1 mod 7))
6. We set counter to 0 (1 div 7)
7. We set array[2] to 4
8. We set array[3] to 4

So, the 11th array would be [8 5 4 4]

Comment: Suppose I call counter_to_array(10,4)

It makes a new variable array with a dimension of 4; is that array[4] ?

then a loop that goes from 0 to 4.
and then n = 3;
counter = 3;
array[0]=3;
array[1]=3;
and so on.

then i get an array full of 3s ? 

I am sure am missing a lot. Please explain. I was wrong. Can you be language specific? I thought I could understand from a general representation. But i was mistaken. I did not understand the purpose % 7 :( Thank You.

Comment: @oasa The counter is divided by 7 on each round, I added a worked example, I hope that helps.

Comment: I really could not follow. May be because of my noobness. Np. I found it from @amit 's answer. Thank you anyways. Always appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that uses a while loop is given below.  The code is in C++ and require # for the include and define statements

```
include <iostream>
define MAXROWS 9
define MAXVALUES 9

using namespace std;
char display[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

int main() {

int arrs[MAXROWS];  // represent the different variables in the for loops

bool status = false;

for (int r=0;r<MAXROWS;r++)
    arrs[r] = 0;  // Initialize values

while (!status) { 

    int total = 0;
    // calculate total for exit condition
    for (int r=0;r<MAXROWS;r++)
        total +=arrs[r];
    // test for exit condition
    if (total == (MAXVALUES-1)*MAXROWS)
        status = true;

    // printing
    for (int r=0;r<MAXROWS;r++)
        cout << display[arrs[r]]; // print(arrs[r])
    cout << endl;  // print(endline)

    // increment loop variables
        bool change = true;
    int r = MAXROWS-1;  // start from innermost loop
    while (change && r>=0) {
        // increment the innermost variable and check if spill overs
        if (++arrs[r] > MAXVALUES-1) {        
            arrs[r] = 0;  // reintialize loop variable
            // Change the upper variable by one
            // We need to increment the immediate upper level loop by one
            change = true;
        }
        else
            change = false; // Stop as there the upper levels of the loop are unaffected

        // We can perform any inner loop calculation here arrs[r]

        r=r-1;  // move to upper level of the loop

    }

}
```

[Link]http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/759707/Generating-dynamically-nested-loops
It shows how a simple multiple nested loop can be converted to a dynamic one without using recursion.